# in Swift how to make a phone call with no confirmation dialog?

Tags: swift, phone-call

for my company, I need my app to make periodically some phone call to a given number and then analyze call quality.

I'm testing

```
private func callNumber(phoneNumber:String) {

    if let phoneCallURL = URL(string: "telprompt://\(phoneNumber)") {

        let application:UIApplication = UIApplication.shared
        if (application.canOpenURL(phoneCallURL)) {
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                application.open(phoneCallURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(phoneCallURL as URL)

            }
        }
    }
}
```

but this code requires for a an "ok" on confirmation dialog. How can I avoid it? I found some answer, but they are old and in objective c

Comment: I dont see why Apple would want to allow a developer to make random calls whenever it wants without asking the user if they want it done. it could be misused  in a number of ways. If the documentation says that you can't do it... theres a very good chance that you can't do it

Comment: What if i want to make a personal app that I want to allow to make calls on my behalf, then there should be an option to do so....

Answer (score -1):

Taken from the iOS SDK Release Notes for iOS 10.3 https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-10.3/

> openURL
>
> When a third party application invokes openURL: on a tel://, facetime://, or facetime-audio:// URL, iOS displays a prompt and requires user confirmation before dialing.

Comment: yes, I read it, I'm now looking for a way to make it in background, automatically.